# Issue With Function Continuation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I know this is probably a very simple fix, but I cannot seem to make the code work. Here is the problematic excerpt:

```
def main_menu():
    print("Welcome! Please Choose An Option to Proceed")
    print("1. New: Input Letters Into A New Excel Document")
    print("2. Add: Add New Letters To An Existing Excel Document")
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter Option Number: ")    
        if choice.lower() in ['1','2']:
            return choice.lower()
        else:
            print("Invalid Number Choice")
            continue

def menu_choice(main_menu):
    while True:
        choice = main_menu()
        if choice == "1":
            newsession()
        elif choice == "2":
            addsession()
        else:
            break

def newsession():
    while True:
        try:    
            txtfilenameinput = input("1. Enter 'Txt' Input File Name: ")
            inputfilename = txtfilenameinput.replace(".txt" , "")
            inputfile = codecs.open(inputfilename + ".txt" , "r" , encoding = "utf-8" , errors = "ignore")
            print("File Found" + "\n")
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File Not Found: Make Sure The File Is Spelled Correctly And That Both The Program and File Is On The Desktop Screen" + "\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()

closeprogram = input("Press Enter Key To Close Program")
```

My objective is, for example, when an input of "1" is inserted in main_menu(), the script would then start to run the newsession() function. Yet for some reason, the program does nothing but jumps to the end of the script (a "press key to close program" command) without engaging the newsession() function. This holds true for an input of "2" for the addsession() function as well. What am I doing wrong? I have tried everything but nothing allows my input choice of 1 or 2 to continue the progress in my script. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. It allows to exit from the program and it returns again and again for more user input:

```
def main_menu():
    print("Welcome! Please Choose An Option to Proceed")
    print("1. New: Input Letters Into A New Excel Document")
    print("2. Add: Add New Letters To An Existing Excel Document")
    print(" QUIT with 'q'")

    while True:
        choice = input("Enter Option Number: ")    
        if choice.lower() in ['1','2','q']:
            return choice.lower()
        else:
            print("Invalid Number Choice")
            continue

def menu_choice(main_menu):
    while True:
        choice = main_menu()
        if choice == "1":
            newsession()
        elif choice == "2":
            addsession()
        else:
            break
```

The problem with your code was that you were "trapped" in a `while True:` loop with no escape. So after ONE single user choice `newsession()` or `addsession()` were started again and again with no further progress in the script and no way to change anything about it except to kill the program. Remember: each `while True` loop should have at least one line containing `brake` or `return`, else it is a never ending story ...

The problem with not reaching the `newsession()` is HERE:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_menu()
```

where it should be:

> `if __name__ == '__main__':
>       menu_choice()`

Comment: Thank you for these fixes; I have applied them as well! However, I am still having the same issue that if "Choice == 1" is true (user entered a 1), newsession() still will not be called to run. I try to test the script but it still just cuts to the end, almost as if "def newsession():" doesn't exist, but it certainly does. Is there anything else you can think of that could be causing the problem? Thank!

Comment: The only way to find out is if you post the ENTIRE code ... at least how you invoke this functions (the code of the `def newsession()` or ` is not required for that)

Comment: I added more code as an edit to my main comment. new session() is extremely long so I cut it down; let me know if anything else in that could be causing the issue. Also, addsession() isn't in the code yet as it isn't written; I had this issue first and wanted to solve it before moving on to that. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Now you can accept this answer as it solves all the issues you have mentioned in the question, right?

Comment: That's it! How amazing that one change can fix the whole code. I've accepted the answer. Thank you again!